# Many textboxes with the same ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, c#-4.0, for-loop

I have the code below:

```
                <%for (int index = 1; index < 7; ++index) {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="indicacao_gdp">
                                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="inp_txt_indicacao_<%= index %>" CssClass="inp_txt_indicacao" runat="server" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="codigo_debito_credito_gdp">
                                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="inp_txt_codigo_debito_credito_<%= index %>" CssClass="inp_txt_codigo_debito_credito" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="descricao_debito_credito_gdp">
                                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="inp_txt_descricao_debito_credito_<%= index %>" CssClass="inp_txt_descricao_debito_credito" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="valor_debito_credito_gdp">
                                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="inp_txt_valor_debito_credito_inteiro_<%= index %>" CssClass="inp_txt_valor_inteiro" runat="server" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
                                ,
                                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="inp_txt_valor_debito_credito_decimal_<%= index %>" CssClass="inp_txt_valor_decimal" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <%}%>
```

But, the code not working...

```
Parser Error Message: 'inp_txt_indicacao_<%= index %>' is not a valid identifier.
```

How I solved?

Comment: Use a `Repeater` or `GridView`

Comment: ***You cannot do `<%= index %>` at ID property, although other properties such as CssClass allow that kind binding.***

Comment: I think you mean to append the same `index` value to several `TextBox` ID's and not actually have `TextBox` controls with same ID's.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I try with Repeater, but no working too.

Comment: @FabianoLothor Telling us that it's not working doesn't help us.  You should 1) provide the code that you're using 2) explain *specfically* what isn't working.  Are you getting an error, is the output incorrect, if so what should it be, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `PlaceHolder` control and dynamically add `TextBox` controls to it from code-behind. In code-behind you can easily set an ID and whatever other properties you like.

See [MSDN: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx).

Comment: This is a lot harder to do, and work with, than using something like a `Repeater`/`GridView`.

Comment: If you want to generate specific id's I believe that's the easiest way to go. And what if `TextBox` controls are not data-bound??

Comment: I don't really see a compelling need to have specific IDs, but rather the OP isn't familiar with either `Repeater` or `GridView`, and so didn't know they were an option.  If you don't have any data to bind to them, then you can just not bind any fields to those controls.  If there is no input data, but rather only output data, you can just bind blank values as input so that you can look at the output.

Comment: @Servy Hi, I solved my problem using the FindControl function in GridView. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this? If you use runat="server" the controls will never have the same ID. If you wrap these text-boxes in a container with a class you can easily obtain data from these elements through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

When you use runat="server" you are creating .net object and not actual html.

You have two options, you can use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) and set the id to ID="inp_txt_indicacao" (.net will take care of making it unique).

Or instead of having <asp:TextBox you put regular

```
<input type="textbox" id="inp_txt_indicacao_<%= index %>" />
```

**Repeater**

There's a lot of good tutorial online but here's a quick understanding.

To use a repeater, you'll need to put your data in a list of some sort.

```
Public Class TestClass

    Public Sub New(ByVal v1 As String, ByVal v2 As String)

        Value1 = v1
        Value2 = v2

    End Sub

    Public Property Value1() As String
    Public Property Value2() As String

End Class

    Dim tc As New List(Of TestClass)

    tc.Add(New TestClass("aa", "bb"))
    tc.Add(New TestClass("cc", "dd"))
    tc.Add(New TestClass("ee", "ff"))
```

You just need to bind the data to the repeater

```
    rpData.DataSource = tc
    rpData.DataBind()


    <asp:Repeater ID="rpData" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtValue1" Text='<%# Bind("Value1") %>' runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtValue2" Text='<%# Bind("Value2") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: OK, but... I need set the textbox value in Code Behind. And I never use a Repeater in a similar case.

Comment: The better form is using the FindControl function.